# What does "suite your self" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I have heard from some of TV series. They are saying "suite your self", what does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure they're saying "suite"? I think it more likely they're saying "suit yourself."

> **suit yourself** — Have it your way, however you like it, do what you like, etc.

Comment: Suit yourself is a form of "as it suits you", with the definition as stated above.

Comment: @gayancc, Note that "suite" and "suit" are pronounced quite differently, so it should be easy to tell which they're using on the TV show.

Comment: thanks robusto and martha and zoot this is what i want to know i got the idea :)

Comment: "Suite" and "suit" _should be_ pronounced quite differently, but here in Western Pennsylvania, people speak of a "bedroom suite" (of furniture) and pronounce it "suit".